# Form Post Data As Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm trying to integrate an API builder to my control panel through a form or post data. I can't figure out how to put the post data as the value for the array.

I tried using `print_r($_POST['VALUE'])` with and without quotes.

I tried using just `$_POST['VALUE']` with and without quotes.

I also tried to set `$value = $_POST['VALUE']` then using `$value` with and without quotes but that caused an error 500.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
    $res = $api->remoteCall('requestLogin', array(
        'type' => 'external',               
        'domain' => 'print_r($_POST['domain'])',            
        'lang' => 'en',                     
        'username' => 'print_r($_POST['uname'])',       
        'password' => 'print_r($_POST['pass'])',    
        'apiUrl' => '127.0.0.1',                
        'uploadDir' => '/web/'.print_r($_POST['domain']).'/public_html',
```

I apologize as I am new to PHP, but thank you in advance.

Comment: Doing `'domain' => $_POST['domain']),` should work.

Comment: It's not the main reason of the error, but just for you to know, It should be `print_r($_POST['domain'], TRUE)`, read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). But actually, you don't need to do `print_r()` to `$_POST['domain']`. Just `$_POST['domain']` it's fine.

Comment: @Sean maybe right, he just have typos in `)`. Try to remove the `'`. Like this, `'domain' => $_POST['domain']'` or if you really want quotation :) you should use `"` like this, `'domain' => "$_POST['domain']"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what other logic is being done there, how the post variables are being sent to the script your sample code is running on, or any of the other details which might point towards a more complete solution but here are some basic tips to help you troubleshoot.

The post variables should be formatted like this:

```
$res = $api->remoteCall('requestLogin', array(
    'domain' => $_POST['domain'],
```

You can dump the entire post array to the screen by doing

```
print_r($_POST);
```

This should output your array to the screen so you can verify that you're receiving the post data in the code and should help you fix any typos or misnamed post variables. If the array has the key as $_POST['domainName'] and you're echoing $_POST['domain']

You're calling code (the "form or post data") should have the post fields in place and named correctly in order for them to be sent to the script

```
<input type="text" name="domain">
```

You should be performing some basic validation on your post fields before adding them to something that's going to be stored anywhere or sent off to a third-party. At the most minimal you'll want to check that there is a value being set for the essential fields (required fields) and I'd look to make sure the values are matching requirements of the API you're passing them off to.

Answer (score 0):

Several things may go wrong when using api. POST values, input values, API call or connection or maybe api response. So not only at the time of implementation and coding but also when integrating api call script with the application there should be some sort of testing and error handling in place. A simple script can be like this

```
$error = array();
$request = array();
$request['type'] = 'external';               
if (isset($_POST['domain']) && !empty($_POST['domain'])) {
    $request['domain'] = $_POST['domain'];
    $request['uploadDir'] = "/web/{$_POST['domain']}/public_html";
 } else {
    $error[] = "Domain is empty";
 }                
if (isset($_POST['uname']) && !empty($_POST['uname'])) {
    $request['username'] = $_POST['uname'];
 } else {
    $error[] = "Username is empty";
 }  
if (isset($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $request['password'] = $_POST['pass'];
 } else {
    $error[] = "Username is empty";
 } 
$request['lang'] = 'en';
$request['apiUrl'] = '127.0.0.1';       
if (count($error) > 0) {
    echo implode( "<br>" , $error );
} else {
    try{
        $res = $api->remoteCall('requestLogin',$request);
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        print_r($e);
        exit();
    }
}
```